# Several Rails many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

I'm creating an app that will have several many to many relationships. Here is one example: An app user will have several skills. At the same time, many job_posts will have several skills. I'd like to be able to reuse the skill models so I could have something like this:

```
    User----has_many----->Skill(smart)<---has_many----job_posting
                              ^
                              |
                           has_many
                              |
                          Application
```

So you see, I want to basically be able to create one skill (in this example: "smart"), and then reference that skill from several different models using has_many relationships.

**What is the best way to do this?** I'd like to avoid creating a bunch of extra models to handle the relationships since I have several of these setups in my app.

In the end, it would be nice to be able to do something like this:
myUser.skills.add(Skill.find(1))
myCompany.skills.add(Skill.find(1))...

P.S.
I know there is no such thing as skills.add(). Please suggest what I could use instead if you have something constructive. Thanks :)

P.P.S
I'm using mysql as my database

Comment: You'll need to set up a DB table to hold the relationship information. Look into using `has_many :through`

Comment: hmm, that's what I was hoping to avoid :/, especially since I would have to make one for each relationship type for each setup like this

Comment: How else were you thinking it could be done? You *could* take the inefficient route and avoid relationship tables by adding foreign keys all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is a typical example of polymorphic association.You can check the relevant documentation [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) at section 2.9. In your case you could use

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :skillable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills, as: :skillable
end

class JobPosting< ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills, as: :skillable
end
```

Comment: Awesome! I think I should be able to use this and just add a method to Skill to allow me to create a hash out of the object so I can do something like user.skills.create(Skill.find(1).hashify())

Comment: You can add a skill to your models like this user.skills << Skill.find(1)

Comment: That's awesome! I think that allows me to get by with only 1 true many to many relationship! You're a real lifesaver! btw, do you know what this does in the background? How is the db keeping track of this?

Comment: You can see this in the documentation that I refererenced. The tables structure is also provided.